# Visio Change Shape Data/Properties with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, visio

for a project I am creating a UserForm that reads values from textboxes and generates Shapes with the data.
So after dropping a shape I want to change the Shape Data rows, for example "Prop.SO_Name".

When I use

```
shp.CellsU("Prop.SO_Name").FormulaU = """Test"""
```

It works just fine. But I want to read a value from the textbox. I tried

```
Dim cell As Visio.cell
Set cell = shp.Cells("Prop.SO_Name")
cell.FormulaU = TextBox2.Value
```

But it returns a runtime error. I also tried

```
Dim str as String
str = Textbox2.value
Dim cell As Visio.cell
Set cell = shp.Cells("Prop.SO_Name")    
cell.FormulaU = str
```

With the same result.

I looked into the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/cell-formulau-property-visio/%22documentation%22) for the FormulaU Property but they do it, apparently, just like I tried. Clearly I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Try use

```
Dim cell As Visio.cell  
Set cell = shp.Cells("Prop.SO_Name")  
cell.FormulaU = chr(34) & UserForm1.TextBox2.Value & chr(34)
```

**Update** You try write string to ShapeSheet cell ! The double quotes within the string is one way to tell VB[A] to make a string with embedded quote mark characters in it.